# Онлайн компилятор для персонального сайта

Tags: c++, online

Можно ли установить какой-то онлайн компилятор на персональном сайте?

Я хочу обеспечить проверку [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) кода на своем сайте.

Comment: а с++ причем тут?

Comment: Компилятор на собственном сайте? Но зачем?

Comment: Конечно, можно. Например, gcc вполне себе бежит на http://ideone.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не разбирался как оно реализовано с точки зрения интеграции в web-страницу, но например на [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) есть возможность нажав на кнопку <kbd>Run this code</kbd> выполнить приведенный код.

Как можно понять из надписи:

> Powered by Coliru online compiler

в качестве ядра используются возможности сайта http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Поэтому можно поискать ответы на упомянутом сайте, как правильно использовать их API для доступа к онлайн-компилятору.

P.S. Список онлайн компиляторов C++ можно найти в [описании](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2B%2B/info) метки [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)